# Tibco 6.4 Subprocess Dynamic Override

Tags: overriding, tibco

i'm using Tibco 6.4 and I need to call different process with the process name dynamic override function.
This is my xpath `if(1=1) then '/Company.bwp' else '/Router.bwp'`;
this two subprocess are in the same directory of the subprocess that using the procedure:

```
/transcoding/router/General.bwp
/transcoding/router/Country.bwp
/transcoding/router/Router.bwp
```

but on debug there's an error:

> BX-600018: Process [Company.bwp] not found.

In Tibco 5 it's easy to use that function but in 6.4 ? I've done a lot of test but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is: tibco 6 don't need path of subprocess like tibco 5.

To call differente subprocess with an dynamic procedure you've to insert the complete name of the process.
In my case, the complete name is `'transcoding.router.country'`.

I've done a concat with input parameters so the override is dynamic for different process.

Someone can check if it's correct?

Thanks